# Acknowledge when method is one-way?

Tags: wcf

In wcf when i send to method which is `one way`-

- I don't need to get answer now...
- later,I need to get an answer for sure.

But how can I be sure that he got the message (to deal with it later )?

What about the 202 reponse ?

http://thejoyofcode.com/One_Way_operations_in_services.aspx

Comment: To be sure he got it; don't make it one way.

Comment: @Hasan Khan , but if the process of the message takes a long time for him to retreive now , but later , how can i do that ?

Comment: Use NServiceBus instead of WCF then

Comment: @Hasan Khan but i know that the server does return a 202 response ... http://thejoyofcode.com/One_Way_operations_in_services.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [article](http://thejoyofcode.com/One_Way_operations_in_services.aspx) that you linked to does a nice job explaining it:

> a one-way service call doesn't wait for the call to be processed, only
>   to be **delivered** - where delivery includes deserialization of the
>   request.

**If you don’t get an exception then the message was successfully acknowledged as received.**

IsOneWay introduces asynchronous aspects to your API. If you choose to go that route and you want to know what happened after the message was received, you’ll have to build that mechanism yourself. At a high level there’s nothing WCF specific about the solution. Either:

1. Call the service back and ask what the result was –OR–
2. Have the service call you back when its done